# Taking a Mongo DB dump

Tags: mongodb

I've seen the `mongodump` command used to export a specific database, but how can I find the name of the available databases before choosing one?

To confirm, is this correct?

`mongodump -d <database_name> -o <directory_backup>`

Also, what effect will the command alone, without any flags, have if run on the database? Thanks!

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on mongodump (a quick web search will net you the reference page and examples). Enumerating databases is pretty trivial as well - `show dbs` . That said, this really is a mongodb maintenance question, not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You're right. I kind of defaulted to SO without thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the databases available with

`show dbs`

If you do not specify a database it will dump all databases.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--db

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise at first I had to run `mongo` first before `show dbs`. I thought it'd dump all databases, but there's no new dump in the usual location. What location will it use if one isn't specified?